# gcc generates .h.gch files even though there's no .h files in compiler

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, makefile, avr

We are making a makefile for a class project, and we are having problems with gcc generating `.h.gch` files. Looked around on stack overflow and apparently it is normally caused by either including `.h` files in dependencies or having something like `#include *.cpp`, which we did not do in our makefile.

We get this error when we compile, change a file and compile again. For now we can fix it with `make clean` before compiling again, but if possible we'd like to prevent the `.h.gch` file from being generated:

```
avr-gcc -I. -MMD  -g -mmcu=atmega324pa -Os -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -funsigned-bitfields -funsigned-char -Wall -fno-exceptions -c pwm.cpp pwm.h interruptNormal.h
cc1: warning: the "stabs" debug format cannot be used with pre-compiled headers [-Wdeprecated]
In file included from pwm.h:5:0:
interruptNormal.h:8:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class InterruptNormal{
 ^~~~~
interruptNormal.h:8:22: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '_attribute_' before '{' token
 class InterruptNormal{
                      ^
pwm.h:7:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class Pwm : public InterruptNormal{
 ^~~~~
pwm.h:7:11: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '_attribute_' before ':' token
 class Pwm : public InterruptNormal{
           ^
cc1: warning: the "stabs" debug format cannot be used with pre-compiled headers [-Wdeprecated]
interruptNormal.h:8:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class InterruptNormal{
 ^~~~~
interruptNormal.h:8:22: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '_attribute_' before '{' token
 class InterruptNormal{
                      ^
make: * [Makefile:146: pwm.o] Error 1
```

part of the makefile (not sure how much I could post since we would like to avoid problems with plagiarism):

```
PRJSRC= $(wildcard *.cpp)
CPPFILES=$(filter %.cpp, $(PRJSRC))
OBJDEPS=$(CPPFILES:.cpp=.o)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

%.hex: %.out
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .text -j .data \
        -O $(HEXFORMAT) $< $@
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, what's the exact string returned by `vr-gcc --version`?

Comment: ```vr-gcc --version``` says command not found, but ```avr-gcc --version``` gives ```avr-gcc (Fedora 7.4.0-5.fc30) 7.4.0```

Comment: Why are header paths such as `pwm.h` being passed to the compile command?  I'm fairly certain that's that's the source of your problem.  Presumably they're prerequisites specified in another rule (not shown) that then become part of the `$^` builtin variable.

Comment: Because the OP probably confused `$^` with `$<` which should be used in this case.

Comment: @raspy it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> `avr-gcc -I. ... -c pwm.cpp pwm.h interruptNormal.h`

You are compiling `.h` files, this means GCC generates pre-compiled headers for these files, i.e. `.h.gch`.

Presumably, that is not what you want.  Remove the `.h` files from the compilation and clean up `.gch` files from the folder.